# saving pandas dataframe as hdf5

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas version 0.19.1 (with py27-tables-3.2.2_1 and hdf5-1.10.0 installed on my system), I am trying to save a pandas dataframe as a .h5 with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(5), B=range(5)))
df.to_hdf('savefile.h5', 'table', mode='w')
```

However the following error results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1138, in to_hdf
    return pytables.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 270, in to_hdf
    f(store)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 264, in <lambda>
    f = lambda store: store.put(key, value, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 873, in put
    self._write_to_group(key, value, append=append, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1315, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2864, in write
    self.attrs.ndim = data.ndim
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/attributeset.py", line 461, in __setattr__
    self._g__setattr(name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/attributeset.py", line 403, in _g__setattr
    self._g_setattr(self._v_node, name, stvalue)
  File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 696, in tables.hdf5extension.AttributeSet._g_setattr (tables/hdf5extension.c:7549)
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5A.c", line 634, in H5Awrite
    not an attribute

End of HDF5 error back trace

Can't set attribute 'ndim' in node:
 /table (Group) ''.
```

Could someone provide a simple working example of how to save a pandas dataframe in hdf5 format.

Comment: Your code worked on my machine (using pandas 3.5 and pandas 0.19.1)

Comment: Also worked on python 2.7, with pandas 0.19.1 and  tables (3.3.0)

Comment: Look like it's the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13127).

Answer (score 0):

pytables is currently not compatible with hdf5-1.10 as reported in this [issue on github](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/545), downgrading to hdf5-0.8 is the recommended solution.